# How to overload the '+' and '<<' operator in myself class

Tags: c++

I create the class 'Point', overload the operator '+' between 2 Point object and the operator '<<' to show the Point object. I can't compile and run the code. 
The error is that there is no operator "<<" matched. This is occured to "cout << "p3: " << (p1+p2) << endl;"

```
 class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x=0, int y=0) : _x(x), _y(y) {};
        Point operator +(Point &p);
        int getX() {
            return _x;
        }
        int getY() {
            return _y;
        }
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Point &p);
    private:
        int _x, _y;
    };

    Point Point::operator +(Point &p) {
        Point np(this->_x+p.getX(), this->_y+p.getY());
        return np;
    }

    ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, Point &p) {
        out << '(' << p._x << ',' << p._y << ')';
        return out;
    }

    int main() {
        Point p1(1, 2);
        Point p2;
        cout << "p1: " << p1 << endl;
        cout << "p2: " << p2 << endl;
        cout << "p3: " << (p1+p2) << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: there is no the operator "<<" matched

Comment: occur in this "cout << "p3: " << (p1+p2) << endl;"

Comment: Don't comment. Edit your question and add the exact error message.

Comment: _FULL_ error, please.  This might be due to your class ignoring _const-correctness_.

Comment: You need to change the `operator<<` function as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954015/434551.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
(p1+p2)
```

is an rvalue. The function

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, Point &p)
```

expects a reference to `Point`. You can't pass an rvalue to this function. Change it to

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, const Point &p)
```

in the declaration and the definition.

Comment: Note that the update should be made to both the operator definition as well as the friend declaration. (For OP, not you.)

Comment: if I want "cout << (p1+p2)" correct, how can i write the code？

Comment: @dongdong Read the last line of my answer

Comment: It will also be needed to make getX and getY const

Answer (score 2):

C++ only allows a temporary to be passed to a const reference. See this: [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Modify a temporary is meaningless. You need to define a const reference to promise you won't modify it and extend its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

When overloading operators, const correctness is not optional. The following prototypes are what you require...

```cpp
        Point operator + (const Point &p) const;
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Point &p);
```

Comment: Why do you think so? Is this 
a compiler extension? Do you have a reference for required constness in operator+?https://wandbox.org/permlink/72yCgKftGGHVEIsi

Comment: Ok, so you recommend it for possible special cases in the future but in the current example in the question it's not required, is it? It would be even possible to change the arguments. Of course you can't pass rvalues in that case.

Comment: `Point operator + (Point &p) { ++p._x; ++_x; return *this; }` is valid but not recommended.